# How do I get the line in a file with the highest oracle version number

Tags: linux

```
dummy101:/opt/oracle/product/19.7.0.0.200414:N
dummy201:/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0.1.180717:N
```

Result should be:

```
dummy101:/opt/oracle/product/19.7.0.0.200414:N
```

Comment: Please try to be more general in your question next time. The fact that the actual thing you're trying to sort by represents "oracle version" is irrelevant - it could represent anything else, and people who are not familiar with oracle might decide to skip this question. Instead, ask something such as, "how can I get the line in a file with the highest versions string in some field".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the path of the second field is always the same (in your case, `/opt/oracle/product/`) and only the version changes, you can run:

```
sort -V -t: -k 2,2 |head -1
```

Where `-t` sets the field separator to a colon, `-k 2,2` sorts the table by the second field, `-V` is for "natural sort of (version) numbers within text", and `head -1` shows the first line only, which is the line with the higher oracle version.

Comment: WHat is one of them is installed in different path?